# cherrypy not working as expected using multiple servers and multiple ports

Tags: python, cherrypy

I would like to serve two separate classes on two separate ports using cherrypy.  One class is private and want it served only on a port that is blocked by the firewall and want to use a server that requires credentials.  The other I want public.

Here is my code:

```
import cherrypy
from cherrypy import _cpserver
from cherrypy import _cpwsgi_server

class TestPublic:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return 'welcome!'

class TestPrivate:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return 'secret!'        

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    users = {'admin':'password'}
    config1 = {'/':{
        'server.thread_pool' : 50,
        'server.environment' : 'production',
        }}
    config2 = {'/admin':{
        'server.thread_pool' : 50,
        'tools.digest_auth.on': True,
        'tools.digest_auth.realm': 'Some site',
        'tools.digest_auth.users': users,
        }}    

    cherrypy.server.unsubscribe()
    cherrypy.tree.mount(TestPublic(), script_name ='/', config=config1)
    cherrypy.tree.mount(TestPrivate(), script_name ='/admin', config=config2)        
    server1 = _cpserver.Server()
    server2 = _cpserver.Server()
    server1.bind_addr = ('0.0.0.0', 8080)
    server2.bind_addr = ('0.0.0.0', 8888)
    adapter1 = _cpserver.ServerAdapter(cherrypy.engine, server1)
    adapter2 = _cpserver.ServerAdapter(cherrypy.engine, server2)
    adapter1.subscribe()
    adapter2.subscribe()

    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

It ends up not serving anything on 8888 and it serves the private class on port 8080!

I'm using cherrypy 3.1.2

I'm attempting to follow these examples: [1](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/MultipleHttpServers) [2](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/process/servers.html#multiple-servers-ports) [3](http://www.zacwitte.com/running-cherrypy-on-multiple-ports-example)
which are very different from each other, are incomplete, or appear to have errors.

Comment: Why don't you use two separate servers? That might be necessary from a security point of view anyway because the server that has access to the private content can run as a different uid.

Comment: @Celada  That's what I think I am doing.  server1 and server2 are separate server instances.  Do you have something else in mind?

Comment: I think that using the vhost dispatcher can help you. request.dispatch = cherrypy.dispatch.VirtualHost(**{...})

Comment: What I meant (and should have said) is two completely separate Python scripts, one for each server. But Anders Waldenborg's suggestion looks interesting, you might try that first.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that you call `cherrypy.tree.mount()` for both instances. But this mounts *both* of them in the same CherryPy instance, with `TestPrivate` effectively overwriting `TestPublic`. This is also why only the private server is visible.

Even if mounting several root objects was possible (and as far as I have figured it currently isn't), there is no place in your code where you explicitly assign `server1` to `TestPublic` and `server2` to `TestPrivate`. You just call `subscribe()` and hope for CherryPy to figure it out - that will not work.

As Anders Waldenborg noted, check out the VirtualHost dispatcher:

http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/_cpdispatch.html#cherrypy._cpdispatch.VirtualHost

But for that you have to combine your two root objects into one.

Else, just start two separate CherryPy processes, as suggested by Celada.